# getParameterInfo datatype for creating new feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase, feature-class, python-toolbox

I'm having trouble finding a suitable datatype that allows the user to browse to a .gdb and create a name for a new feature class. DEFeatureClass wants an existing FC to write to. Using CreateFeatureclass_management to do so before the user browses to the .gdb and enters the name doesn't seem to work. This is for a Python Toolbox in 10.2.2

Comment: Have you set your *direction* to output?

Comment: Couldn't your tool just have two fields - one to browse to a workspace of type geodatabase, and the other to take a string as the name for your new feature class - and then use tool validation to check whether the feature class name provided already exists?